# Capture word between optional hyphens regex

Tags: regex, perl

I've following type of strings,

```
abc - xyz
abc - pqr - xyz
abc - - xyz
abc - pqr uvw - xyz
```

I want to retrieve the text `xyz` from 1st string and `pqr` from 2nd string, `` (empty) from 3rd & `pqr uvw`. The 2nd hyphen is optional. `abc` is static string, it has to be there. I've tried following regex,

```
/^(?:abc) - (.*)[^ -]?/
```

But it gives me following output,

```
xyz
pqr - xyz
- xyz
pqr uvw - xyz
```

I don't need the last part in the second string. I'm using perl for scripting. Can it be done via regex?

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/WoP9T9/2

Comment: @S.Kablar please try not to answer in comments, and more, with an external link. A proper answer, why not with some explanation, would be so much better..

Comment: Perfect! It works. @S.Kablar If you can add answer and some explanation, I can mark it as answer.

Comment: Is `abc` dynamic or static? If it is static, just use `/^abc\h*-\h*(\S+)/`

Comment: It is static, but based on the regex given by @S.Kablar, I was able to modify it to work for `abc`.

But there is only one issue, the regex can't handle `abc - - xyz`. Adding it in question.

Comment: What do you expect to get for the `abc - - xyz` string? Do you expect an empty string? Try [`^abc\h*-\h*([^-\s]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/JrVe5x/2)

Comment: What about [`^[^-]+-\s\K[^-\s]*`](https://regex101.com/r/WoP9T9/3)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the text between hyphen can have spaces. it needn't be single word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `(.*)` part is a greedily quantified dot and it grabs any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, up to the end of the line and the `[^ -]?`, being able to match an empty string due to the `?` quantifier (*1 or 0 repetitions*), matches the empty string at the end of the line. Thus, `pqr - xyz` output for `abc - pqr - xyz` is only logical for the regex engine.

You need to use a more restrictive pattern here. E.g.

```
/^abc\h*-\h*((?:[^\s-]+(?:\h+[^\s-]+)*)?)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JrVe5x/5).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `abc` - an `abc`
- `\h*-\h*` - a hyphen enclosed with 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `((?:[^\s-]+(?:\h+[^\s-]+)*)?)` - Group 1 capturing an optional occurrence of

  - `[^\s-]+` - 1 or more chars other than whitespace and `-`
  - `(?:\h+[^\s-]+)*` - zero or more repetitions of

    - `\h+` - 1+ horizontal whitespaces
    - `[^\s-]+` - 1 or more chars other than whitespace and `-`

Comment: @Abhishek And what about [`^abc\h*-\h*([^-\n]*[^-\s])`](https://regex101.com/r/JrVe5x/3)?

Comment: It works, but it takes `\n` into account as well. I just need to take care of spaces, but not new line.

Comment: @Abhishek It should not now. And it can still return an empty value in Group 1.

Comment: Yes.. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `^[^-]*-\s*\K[^\s-]*`.

Here's how it works:

```
^       # Matches at the beginning of the line (in multiline mode)
[^-]*   # Matches every non - characters
-       # Followed by -
\s*     # Matches every spacing characters
\K      # Reset match at current position
[^\s-]* # Matches every non-spacing or - characters
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TS9H9O/1).

---

Update for multiple enclosed words: `^[^-]*-\s*\K[^\s-]*(?:\s*[^\s-]+)*`

Last part `(?:\s*[^\s-]+)*` checks for existence of any other word preceded by space(s).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TS9H9O/2)

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks.. But updated one, takes \n into account as well. I just need to take care of spaces, but not new line.

Comment: Did you try with horizontal spacing, as suggested by @wiktor?

Answer (score 1):

You could use split:

```
$answer = (split / \- /, $t)[1];
```

Where $t is the text string and you want the 2nd split (i.e. [1] as starts from 0). Works for everything except abc - - xyz but if the separator is " - " then it should have 2 spaces in the middle to return nothing. If abc - - xyz is correct then you can do this before the split for all to work:

```
$t =~ s/\- \-/-  -/;
```

It simply inserts an extra space so it'll match " - " twice with nothing in-between.

Answer (score 0):

> Can it be done via regex?

Yes, with three simple regexes: `-` and `^\s+` and `\s+$`.

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;

open my $INFILE, '<', 'data.txt';

my @results = map {
    (undef, my $target) = split /-/, $_, 3;
    $target =~ s/^\s+//;  #remove leading spaces
    $target =~ s/\s+$//;  #remove trailing spaces
    $target;
} <$INFILE>;

close $INFILE;

say Dumper \@results;

--output:--
$VAR1 = [
          'xyz',
          'pqr',
          '',
          'pqr uvw'
        ];
```